# How to sort a list of files/directories by hierarchical depth?

Tags: sorting, filenames

I am working on implementing my own feature request -- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31601 -- to give `wdired` the ability to handle a `dired-` buffer that contains an arbitrary list of absolute paths to directories and files; e.g.,

```
(dired (directory-files-recursively "/path/to/directory" "" 'include-directories))
```

However, the files and directories may not necessarily be recursive -- i.e., `dired-mode` can handle creating a buffer containing an arbitrary list of files and directories.

I have added *draft* code to `wdired` that places read-only text properties on the `file-name-directory`.  That way, a user cannot edit those portions of the path while in `wdired-mode`.

The next step is to process the renaming of files/directories, which requires they be done in a hierarchical order.  For example, a user may have renamed a directory and a file:

OLD NAME:   `/path/to/directory`

NEW NAME:   `/path/to/the_directory`

OLD NAME:   `/path/to/directory/file`

NEW NAME:   `/path/to/directory/the_file`

OLD NAME:   `/path/to/different_directory`

NEW NAME:   `/path/to/the_different_directory`

OLD NAME:   `/path/to/different_directory/different_file`

NEW NAME:   `/path/to/different_directory/the_different_file`

If we *first* rename the directory from `/path/to/directory` to `/path/to/the_directory`, then `rename-file` will be unable to rename `/path/to/directory/file` because the `directory` no longer exists; i.e., the `directory` was changed to `the_directory`.

Therefore, it makes sense to sort all of the files and directories into a hierarchical order such that the deepest file or directory is processed fist in time when renaming the files/directories.  For example, if we have a set of files that are 5 directories deep, then those should be processed before processing directories or files that are less than 5 deep.

**Q**:  How to sort a list of files/directories by hierarchical depth?

WORKING LIST:

```
'("/path/to/different_directory/different_file"
  "/path/to/directory/file"
  "/X/Y"
  "/a/b/c/d/e/f"
  "/1/2/3/4"
  "/A/B/C/D/e"
  "/x/y/Z"
  "/Z"
  "/path/to/different_directory"
  "/path/to/directory")
```

RESULT DESIRED:

```
'("/a/b/c/d/e/f"
  "/A/B/C/D/e"
  "/path/to/different_directory/different_file"
  "/1/2/3/4"
  "/path/to/directory/file"
  "/x/y/Z"
  "/path/to/different_directory"
  "/path/to/directory"
  "/X/Y"
  "/Z")
```

Comment: Define a function that counts directory "steps"? Anyway, I hope you're considering creating a minor mode for your feature, so that a user can, for example, turn it on and off in Wdired. It would be a shame to just modify Wdired so that it *always* had the behavior you suggest (e.g. read-only directory components).

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for taking a look at this thread.  My understanding of the current behavior of `wdired` is to let the user mistakenly believe that he/she is modifying a component of the `file-name-directory` and then when the user types `C-c C-c` or `wdired-finish-edit`, the proposed edit to the `file-name-directory` cannot be processed:  `(file-error Renaming No such file or directory ...`.  The reason for that error is because only the `file-name-nondirectory` can be edited without errors, and still there would be the problem described above due to processing of hierarchy/directory-steps.

Comment: @Drew -- by placing `read-only` properties on the `file-name-directory`, it prevents the user from mistakenly thinking he/she has edited something successfully and it prevents the above-mentioned `file-error`.  In general, I suggest things through the years to the Emacs team and they choose what, if anything, gets implemented.  I am usually happy if it works in my own setup even if the feature never gets implemented.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that one cannot modify directory components anyway. Yes, it makes sense to prevent someone from trying that and only finding out later that an error is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I am not so sure why you decide to sort `"/1/2/3/4"` before `"/path/to/directory/file"` in your desired result.

If you can skip that specification the solution is rather simple:

```el
(let ((paths
       '("/path/to/different_directory/different_file"
         "/path/to/directory/file"
         "/X/Y"
         "/a/b/c/d/e/f"
         "/1/2/3/4"
         "/A/B/C/D/e"
         "/x/y/Z"
         "/Z"
         "/path/to/different_directory"
         "/path/to/directory")))
  (cl-stable-sort paths
       (lambda (path1 path2)
         (> (cl-count ?/ path1)
            (cl-count ?/ path2)))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I manually placed `"/1/2/3/4"` before `"/path/to/directory/file"` in the proposed desired result for no reason other than each has four (4) components.  Your answer does the job nicely.